# "Unable to load resource" because of "ZipException: invalid entry size"

Tags: java, jnlp, xerces

I have a Java 8 project that creates about a dozen JNLP applications. I have built and run them on Windows successfully. The JNLP launches correctly through `javaws`. I then transfer it as a .tar to a Solaris machine via FTP (in binary mode) and my SA deploys via Tomcat.

When I visit the URL to launch the JNLP over the network, I get an Application Error.

The Exception is:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: https://example.com/webstartdev10g/dev/apps/libs/xerces.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Wrapped Exception is:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 19075 but got 11917 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:287)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:377)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpDownloadHelper.download(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

All of my JNLP apps that depend on xerces have this same error. The apps that don't require xerces seem to be working fine. I checked that the xerces.jar file is the same size on my Windows machine and the Solaris machine. I visited `https://example.com/webstartdev10g/dev/apps/libs/xerces.jar` directly and was able to download the file and open it. I even replaced my local copy with the downloaded version and ran the app locally without any errors. Based on this, it doesn't seem like there is actually anything wrong with the file.

Any ideas to help me narrow this down?

**EDIT:**

I turned on the `javaws -verbose` flag to get more details into what is happening when I launch the JNLP locally with the downloaded jar. As it turns out, I *am* still getting the error, but it isn't preventing the application from launching. It is just being logged in the console silently, with a different size listed.

`java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 19075 but got 16384 bytes)`

I'm still not sure how only this file has this problem or why it reports itself as being the same size on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt, retransfered, and redeployed the apps. They seem to be working now. I am still confused about how the symptoms presented themselves and would be interested in any theories on what happened (other than "the file was somehow corrupted during the transfer").

In any case, using `javaws -verbose` helped me get some clues about the problem and redeploying the tar file resolved the issue.